# Image <a> vertical & horizontal align center and resize with % in both

Tags: html, image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create something like this:
[image]

More specific I have an image  which I want to be placed in the middle (horizontal & vertical) and also the image to be resized according to the screen size as in the picture above. The problem and my question is how can I do that resizing in height and width by using % and at the same time align them in the middle (horizontal & vertical) and all this in an `<a>` tag.
Here is the code I have managed to write so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a id="demo" style="text-align:center;display:block;vertical-align:middle;" class="btn" href="#Modal"><img src="https://media2.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg"></a>


</body>
</html>
```

I have actually tried so many things that I saw for `<img>` or `<a>` aligning but none of them worked to me. I think it is because I have both. I also use bootstrap. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give image width value in %. and anchor in center from all way:

find **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nx6t2wcL/)**

HTML:

```
<a id="demo" class="btn absoluteCenter" href="#Modal"><img src="https://media2.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.absoluteCenter{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);    
}
.absoluteCenter img{
    width:50%;  
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for the answer but the picture resize itself only when I change the width of the browser, not the height. Is it possible to change by the height and the width? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But height is auto. It resizes auto depending in width of the image.

Comment: So we can't have a for example height:30%; like width:50%; ?

Comment: See this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/nx6t2wcL/1/  width:50%; and height:30% of the window width and height. It is done by jquery.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to keep its aspect-ratio, and if you can use flexbox (support from IE 10 onwards) you could have a container `.box` element that takes up 100% of the height of the screen. By setting `justify-content` and `align-items` to `center` you center the contents of the `.box`. The `<a>` gets a `.box__centered` class that sets the width based on the `.box`, and the `<img>` gets a `.box__image` class that makes it as wide as the parent `<a>` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box__centered {
  width: 25%; /* set the percentual width here */
}

.box__image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="box__centered">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/321/321" class="box__image" />
  </a>
</div>
```

If you can't use flexbox, you can position the top left of the `.box__centered` in the center of the screen and use a `transform` to nudge it left and up a little to put its center at the center of the screen.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box__centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 25%; /* set the percentual width here */
}

.box__image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="box__centered">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/321/321" class="box__image" />
  </a>
</div>
```

For both techniques see CSS Tricks' [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) article.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for the answer but the picture resize itself only when I change the width of the browser, not the height. Is it possible to change by the height and the width? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the image to keep its aspect-ratio, so when you e.g. increase the width that the height should also be increased? Do you want the image to always fit in the window, so e.g. when the height becomes too small the image also becomes smaller?

Comment: What I want is: I want the image to cover always for example the 30% of the screens height (without "destroying" its normal appearance like this http://visual.merriam-webster.com/images/communications/communications/typography/set-width.jpg) and be in the middle (vertically & horizontally). Sorry if I didn't make that clear to you and thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Try giving the `box__centered` a `height: 30%` and the `box__image` a `height: 100%; width: auto`

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of [vw and vh units](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) may help you a great deal (for dimensions and margins).

Also have a look to what [jQuery](http://www.innovedesigns.com/web-development-guide/jquery-responsive-detecting-mobile-screens-width-height/) may offer you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make image as background for anchor